# Updating an answer to a question which is marked duplicate

Tags: discussion

I have answered a question and after sometime that particular question was marked as a duplicate.

I have received comment on my answer by author of a question.

Now at this situation will it be appropriate to update the answer with addition/suggestion of code? because once we update it will come onto the active tab. Or just comment him again redirecting to the original one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flag the duplicate question and ask for a merge of the two and you're answer will (when merged) appear on the original one. We all want the best of content, and if your answer is a great one, you will be awarded.